# How to include a Row_Number function at MySQL query

Tags: mysql, window-functions

I would like to generate a row_number function, just like the one we have from SQL server, but directly through the MySQL.

I have the following, but it doesn't work. I'm uncertain where I should set the row_number=0:

```
SET @rownum:=0;
select i.name, sum(quantity) Qtd, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
from orders o join order_items i on o.id = i.order_id
where i.product_id not in ("wpp001", "147426")
group by 1
order by 5 desc
limit 10
```

I have a table like:

```
name | Qtd
A    | 2
A    | 3
B    | 1
C    | 6
```

The result expected:

```
name | Qtd | rownum
C    | 6   | 1
A    | 5   | 2
B    | 1   | 3
```

edit: Corrected the set name variable and the table+output desired

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "it doesn't work." Does it give the wrong result? If so, what result does it return? Does it return an error? If so, what is the exact error?

Answer (score 1):

You would use `row_number()`.  Given that you don't have a fifth column, I assume you intend something like this:

```
select i.name, sum(quantity) as Qtd,
       row_number() over (order by sum(quantity) desc) as rnk
from orders o join
     order_items i
     on o.id = i.order_id
where i.product_id not in ('wpp001', '147426')
group by 1
order by qtd desc
limit 10;
```

MySQL has supported `row_number()` since version 8.0 was released in April 2018.

In older versions, you would use a subquery:

```
select x.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rnk
from (select i.name, sum(quantity) as Qtd
      from orders o join
           order_items i
           on o.id = i.order_id
      where i.product_id not in ('wpp001', '147426')
      group by 1
      order by qtd desc
     ) n cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
limit 10;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not running the 8.0 version yet

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the same name for an user defined variable,

You used one in the SET and another on your code

> ```
> CREATE TABLE orders(id int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1),(2)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE order_items(name varchar(4),product_id int ,quantity int,orde
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO order_items VALUES('A',1,1,1),('b',2,1,1),('A',1,1,2),('b',2,1,2)
> ```

> ```
> SET @rownum:=0;
> ```

> ```
> select i.name, sum(quantity) Qtd, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
> from orders o join order_items i on o.id = i.order_id
> where i.product_id not in ("wpp001", "147426")
> group by 1
> order by 3 desc
> limit 10
> ```
>
> ```
> name | Qtd | rank
> :--- | --: | ---:
> b    |   2 |    2
> A    |   2 |    1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6fe4743cf3847cfee5f736976b3f795d)*